# SPSitedataquery Excluding a particular list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I'am using SPSitedataquery to query to 7 task lists but in all i have 8 task lists but i want to exclude 1 task list from the query how can i do it? Any ideas? Thanks in advance?
Following is my code

```
 SPSiteDataQuery oQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                oQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"171\" />";
                oQuery.Query = string.Concat("<Where>",
                                  "<And>",
                                     "<Neq>",
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Status'/>",
                                        "<Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value>",
                                     "</Neq>",
                                     "<Eq>",
                                        "<FieldRef Name='ReminderDate' />",
                                        "<Value Type='Calculated'><Today /></Value>",
                                     "</Eq>",
                                  "</And>",
                               "</Where>");
                oQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +  /* Title is LastName column </Today>2014-03-29T00:00:00Z*/
                  "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\"/>" +
                   "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\"/>" +
                   "<FieldRef Name=\"Body\"/>" +
                   "<FieldRef Name=\"NewJoiner\"/>" +
                   "<FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>" +
                   "<ListProperty Name=\"Title\"/>";
                oQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";//Recursive
                DataTable dtTasks = oWeb.GetSiteData(oQuery);
```

I want something wherein i can query to all remaining 7 task lists except 1 task list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify in [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.query%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which items to **exclude** from results.

For example, the following query:

```
<Neq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Lookup'>/project/Lists/Tasks</Value></Neq>
```

will exclude all task items from `Tasks` list located on `Project` site.

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that in the query, if you want to use SPSiteDataQuery you will have to do this filtering on the returned objects

Answer (score 2):

When a template is specified, the data is returned from all lists of that type and as mentioned by @Robert, you will then need to filter the returned object. However, there is other way in which you can specify the IDs of the lists instead of template. Example:

```
<Lists>
  <List ID="7A9FDBE6-0841-430a-8D9A-53355801B5D5" />
  <List ID="3D18F506-FCA1-451e-B645-2D720DC84FD8" />
</Lists>
```

So, what you can do: first find all the lists with specific template and generate the Lists node for the `SPSitedataquery`. In this you can exclude/include the lists you want.